# Nginx - Lua Unable to save image file

Tags: linux, nginx, lua, file-permissions

My lua code is something like this:

```
local savefiletarget = "/usr/local/openresty/nginx/webfolder/img/uploadedimg.jpg".
local fileToSave = io.open(savefiletarget,"w+b")
if not fileToSave then
         ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE,'failed to save file : '..savefiletarget);
         ngx.say('{"filename" : "'..filenametosave..'","status" : 0 ,"message":"failed to open file"}')
   return
end
```

Log shows the error:

`failed to save file : /usr/local/openresty/nginx/webfolder/img/uploadedimg.jpg`

I'm using Linux server, do I require permissions to save the image?

Or is there anything I missed?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /usr/local/openresty/nginx/webfolder/img/` ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Output: 
`drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun  1 16:56 /usr/local/openresty/nginx/webfolder/img/`

Comment: To see what is wrong, get the error message with `local fileToSave, message = io.open(savefiletarget,"w+b")`.

Comment: @lhf I'm getting `permission denied` as the result. So how I add permission for nginx? I assume its using the www-data user.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff still getting `Permission Denied`

Comment: 1. look into nginx.conf and confirm it uses `www-data` user -- 2. `chown www-data:www-data /usr/local/openresty/nginx/webfolder/img/ --recursive` (assuming www-data is the correct user) -- 3. `chmod o-rwx /usr/local/openresty/nginx/webfolder/img` and don't EVER set permissions to `o+w` again; it's incredibly dangerous if you forget to change it back and you should never do it without adding 100+ post it notes to your desk to change it back IMMEDIATELY after you're done.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer - I removed my evil comment about `chmod o+w` :-)